# generate a JAR using Maven from open source project, for someone who knows nothing about Maven

Tags: maven, jar, release

I am working on an Android project that I would like to integrate some open source code into, specifically, this: https://github.com/tenaciousRas/android-plist-parser.  I'd like to be able to treat the author's code like a library and just have a `.JAR`I can call.  Direct from the author's readme, the deployment instructions are as follows:

> ### Deployment
>
> The main objective of the project is to provide consumable source code for your application.  Checkout the source code and add it to your Android project, or consider using a maven build to generate a JAR for use in your application (for this, use the release profile or comment out the test module).

OK, so from this it sounds like I want to use a Maven build to generate a JAR using the release profile.  The thing is, I've never used Maven before, so I don't actually know what this entails.  I could spend a long time reading through the Maven documentation and mastering yet another build system, but Maven is really only incidental to what I'm actually trying to achieve.

*Are there any quick steps I can take to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, without needing to become a Maven expert (or amateur) in the process?*  I've started reading about Maven, but it's not looking like this is going to be a simple 5-minute diversion.  I'm all for learning new build/management tools, just not a new one for every small library I integrate into a project.

Comment: The instruction given by author is wrong, He doesn't have a clear understand of Android and Maven. The jar file generated by Maven contains only compiled .class files without all resources, you can't simply use it as a regular jar library.

Comment: if it would be an apklib project you actually can. And if there are no resources and only java code you could even do it with a jar..

Answer (score 0):

The project is not set up to be easily reused. It is using Maven to build an Android application that does the parsing. However to be easy to reuse it would have to provide any parsing code as a separate jar or even better in an apklib.

You can either just take the source code and copy it into your application or restructure the upstream project to build an apklib. If the author wants to do that send them to the Maven Android Developers mailing list and I can help him with questions there..

Answer (score -1):

If the project already contains a pom.xml file, just cd to the directory and run `mvn package`. This will generate a jar in the target folder that then you can import into your project